# Model not loading in my controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have been trying to load the model in my controller, but it does not even when I have configured all the settings. Even with the database, I get no error or anything.

#### My model

```
class dogin extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function hello() {
        $rae = "hello";
        return $rae;
    }
}
```

#### My controller

```
class login extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function lo() {
        $this->load->model('dogin');
        $var = array();
        $var['hello'] = $this->dogin->hello();
        $this->load->view('gifttoday/login',$var);
    }
}
```

I have used just a simple thing, still no result or error, nothing.

Comment: You may wany to capitalise Model class name. Also, are you sure your model is in `application/models` directory? One more thing, can you print `$this->dogin->hello();` before passing it to the view to see if the error is in the model or in the view?.

Comment: capitalize the model name and the controller name. Do not capitalize the php file name. If that does not work try echoing test strings from your controller and then your model. And use $data['hello'] for passing to your view - its a convention that most people use.

Comment: The code seems okay to me. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the controller and above the class definition. I suspect its a PHP error somewhere and you're not seeing it because error reporting must've been turned off

Comment: Yeah the code seems to be ok enable error reporting. also try var_dump($var); before you load view. If you are getting the output then check your view, you might have some bug there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to capitalize the model class name and call it capitalized from your controller. Here is a working version for you.

### controllers/login.php

```
<?

class login extends CI_Controller{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function lo() {

    $this->load->model('Dogin');
    $var = array();
    $var['hello'] = $this->Dogin->hello();
    //$this->load->view('gifttoday/login',$var);
    var_dump($var); //prints hello!
    }
}
```

### models/dogin.php

```
<?

class Dogin extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }



    function hello() {
        $rae = "hello";
        return $rae;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `var_dump ($var);` instead of passing it to the view to see if the value was received from the model.

Comment: Still nothing var dump is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model :

```
class Dogin extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //Do your magic here
    }

    function hello() {
        $rae = "hello";
        return $rae;
    }
}
```

And in your controller (add public to the methods in your controllers if they are public):

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function lo() {

        $this->load->model( 'Dogin' );
        $var = array();
        $var['hello'] = $this->Dogin->hello();
        $this->load->view( 'gifttoday/login', $var );
    }

}
```

And don't forget to paste this in your view :

```
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello every body i have solved the problem it was just an extra "}" i checked my error log and i removed it it was just a syntax error but thanks any way.